# Does a general-purpose disk journalling library exist for .Net?

Tags: .net, journal

I have a requirement to maintain a persistent local journal.  Does a library for .Net already exist, or will I have to write it myself?

Comment: I looked in the usual places and couldn't see anything.  I would guess that each app, activity or case for journalling will have very unique requirements.  What are yours specifically?

Comment: I want to write a byte[] to disk and be notified when it is persisted, so I can process it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No such library exists... yet!